# Share Image element transition display incorrect size

Tags: android, android-animation, universal-image-loader, android-transitions

I have a recycle view to show all photo thumbnail items. When click on item, I use transition for imageview in this item to Detail activity. The problem is that image source is gotten from internet by [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). And **sometime (not always) the images not reload correct size** like this:

[image: transition error]

```
 // on view holder item click
  final Pair<View, String>[] pairs = TransitionHelper.createSafeTransitionParticipants(this, false,
                    new Pair<>(((ItemViewHolder) viewHolder).thumbnail, getString(R.string.TransitionName_Profile_Image)),
                    new Pair<>(((ItemViewHolder) viewHolder).tvName, getString(R.string.TransitionName_Profile_Name)));

  ActivityOptionsCompat transitionActivityOptions = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, pairs);
  startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode, transitionActivityOptions.toBundle());
```

**Detail activity**

```
// try to post pone transition until UIL load finish
ActivityCompat.postponeEnterTransition(this);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layoutContent, new DetailFragment()).commit();
```

**Fragment Detail**

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, imageViewDetail, new ImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                    finishAnimation();
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {

                    finishAnimation();
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
                    finishAnimation();
                }
            });


 private void finishAnimation(){
     ActivityCompat.startPostponedEnterTransition(getActivity());
     imageViewDetail.invalidate();
 }
```

**fragment_detail.xml**

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

     <ImageView
        android:transitionName="@string/TransitionName.Profile.Image"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewDetail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

I even wait views are laid out before load image but still not work:

```
imageViewDetail.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                // code load image from UIL
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Is there any way to avoid this issue?

Comment: You are use centerCrop maybe that's a issue try with different scale type .

Comment: @Himani well, I have to use because the photo must fit screen and keep ratio. But do you have any clue about the scaletype error?  It **does work on many cases**, but sometime look like the image doesn't ready

Comment: then use FITXY to scaletype

Comment: @Himani First, fitXY doesn't keep ratio aspect. Second, still not work.

Comment: @R4j, do you know the aspect ratio of the source images in advance? I had a similar problem with Images. But in my case I knew the aspect ratio of my images in advance, i.e 2:3 . So I had an Image view in which I was changing the imageview dimensions dynamically at runtime based on device screensize. If this is your requirement, I could post the code for doing so.

Comment: @oathkeeper well, my problem isn't image ratio. It's the transition issue. If I turn off transition, it displays correctly. Anyway, thanks for your feedback

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: @kingston no, I quit and remove the transition

Comment: facing same issue, but no answer at your question made me sad.

Answer (score 0):

this xml can handle diferent image size

```
 <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/vScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="51dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/hScroll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none" 
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgFullscreen"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
```

in java

```
fullImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFullscreen);
selectedPhoto = (FeedItem) i.getSerializableExtra(TAG_SEL_IMAGE);
        zoom = 1;

        if (selectedPhoto != null) {
            fetchFullResolutionImage();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getString(R.string.msg_unknown_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }



private void fetchFullResolutionImage() {
    try {
        final URL url = new URL(selectedPhoto.getImge());       
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url
                            .openStream());
                    if (bmp != null)
                        setImage(bmp);
                    else {
                        showToast("Error fetching image!");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
private void setImage(final Bitmap bmp) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                fullImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                adjustImageAspect(selectedPhoto.getWidth(),
                        selectedPhoto.getHeight());
            }
        });
    }
private void adjustImageAspect(int bWidth, int bHeight) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        if (bWidth == 0 || bHeight == 0)
            return;
        int swidth;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13) {
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            swidth = size.x;
        } else {
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            swidth = display.getWidth();
        }

        int new_height = 0;
        new_height = swidth * bHeight / bWidth;
        params.width = swidth;
        params.height = new_height;
        saveW = swidth;
        saveH = new_height;
        fullImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

Comment: My problem is transition issue, not image scaling. Your code simply scale image to fit screen height.